# How to correctly rotate my players? Java

Tags: java, swing

Today I have been working on a basic tank-type game, where two players control their tanks (A green, and a red one), and shoot at eachother. While developing the rotation based movement system, (meaning that the players rotate to point a direction, and then move forward or backwards straight in that direction), I ran into a flaw in my code.

**The issue is that rather than rotating each individual player's image, and THEN placing both of them onto the game screen, I am rotating the entire JFrame Canvas.**

**This causes the first player to work perfectly, but the second player to orbit the first player when he/she rotates.**

Hopefully someone knows how to change my movement system to rotate the player image, and then place it, so each player can individually move without affecting one another.

Here is my player code (Player 1 and Player 2's code is practically identical, apart from the
loaded image, and the names of some variables)

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Player 
{
    imageLoader loader = new imageLoader();
    private BufferedImage player = loader.loadImage("/player2.png");

    public int xPos = 400;
    public int yPos = 400;
    public double degrees = 90.0;

    public Input input;

    public void render(Graphics g)
    {
        ((Graphics2D) g).rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), xPos+16, yPos+16);
        g.drawImage(player, xPos, yPos, null);
    }

    public void moveForward()
    {
        xPos += (int) (Math.sin(degrees * (Math.PI/180)) * 4);
        yPos += (int) (Math.cos(degrees * (Math.PI/180)) * -4);
    }
    public void moveBackward()
    {
        xPos -= (int) (Math.sin(degrees * (Math.PI/180)) * 4);
        yPos -= (int) (Math.cos(degrees * (Math.PI/180)) * -4);
    }
    public void rotateLeft()
    {
        degrees = degrees - 4;
    }
    public void rotateRight()
    {
        degrees = degrees + 4;
    }

}
```

and here is my main Game file (that handles rendering, and drawing the JFrame and such)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class main extends Canvas implements Runnable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 320, HEIGHT = WIDTH/12*9, SCALE = 4;
    public static final String NAME = "Tanks";    

    private JFrame frame;
    public boolean running = false;
    public int tickCount = 0;
    Player player = new Player();
    Player2 player2 = new Player2();
    public Input input;
    Graphics g;
    Graphics2D g2d;

    public main()
    {
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

        frame = new JFrame(NAME);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private synchronized void start()
    {
        running = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    private synchronized void stop()
    {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double nsPerTick = 1000000000D/60D;
        int ticks = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double delta = 0;

        Init();

        while(running)
        {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta+=(now - lastTime)/nsPerTick;
            lastTime = now;
            boolean shouldRender = true;

            while(delta >= 1)
            {
                ticks++;
                tick();
                delta-=1;
                shouldRender = true;
            }
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(shouldRender)
            {
                frames++;
                render();
            }

            if(System.currentTimeMillis()-lastTimer >= 1000)
            {
                lastTimer += 1000;
                //System.out.println("FRAMES: " + frames + "  |  " + "TICKS: " + ticks);
                frames = 0;
                ticks = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        input = new Input(this);
    }

    public void tick() //Updates game
    {
        tickCount++;
        if(input.up.isPressed()) 
        {
            player.moveForward();
        }
        if(input.down.isPressed()) 
        {
            player.moveBackward();
        }
        if(input.left.isPressed()) 
        {
            player.rotateLeft();
        }
        if(input.right.isPressed()) 
        {
            player.rotateRight();
        }
        //Player 2 Controls
        if(input.w.isPressed()) 
        {
            player2.moveForward();
        }
        if(input.s.isPressed()) 
        {
            player2.moveBackward();
        }
        if(input.a.isPressed()) 
        {
            player2.rotateLeft();
        }
        if(input.d.isPressed()) 
        {
            player2.rotateRight();
        }
    }

    public void render() //Print out what is updated
    {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null)
        {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE);

        player.render(g);
        player2.render(g);

        g.dispose(); //Clears up memory
        bs.show(); //Push image to screen
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new main().start();
    }
}
```

Thanks a bunch,

Ryan Corkery

Comment: Have you tried to save the graphics state between renders? I think rotate() is cumulative. You could use getTransform and setTransform to capture state and restore it after each player render.

Comment: As I said the [last time you asked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822446/java-2d-rotation-based-movement-issue), use `Graphics#create` to create a copy on the `Graphics` context.  Do whatever transformation you want on the copy and call `Graphics#dispose` on when you are finished.  This will ensure that the only changes made to the original are what you painted (and not the translations/transformations or other changes you have made to it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a copy of the `Graphics` context using `Graphics#create` and transform/translate it...

```
public void render(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
    g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), xPos+16, yPos+16);
    g2d.drawImage(player, xPos, yPos, null);
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't trust the `render` methods to do the right things...

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
player.render(g2d);
g2d.dispose();
g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
player2.render(g);
g2d.dispose();
```

(about now, I'm thinking, a loop would be really helpful for this)

Comment: Thanks so much, the first response you had made sense to me, but I couldn't quite figure out how to correctly create the graphics image, like you showed in the code above, Works perfectly now!